# Angular.js directives compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

### **Hi everyone,**

> i have one little question , can anyone write some simple example of
>   using compile function with some explaining in directives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually [wrote a blog entry about exactly this](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html).

It goes into a LOT more detail about how it works... but *basically*, it's used like this:

```
// take some HTML
var html = '<div><h2>Some HTML</h2><p ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</p></div>';

// wrap it in an element
var element = angular.element(html);

// compile it as a view with $compile
var compiledView = $compile(element);

// create a scope (if you don't already have one)
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
$scope.items = [
    { name: 'Test Monkey', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Bob Hope', id: 2 }
];

// pass that scope into the compiled view 
// to apply that scope to the view
compiledView($scope);  

// Now all of your directives are wired up and bound to the scope you passed!
```

**NOTE: You shouldn't really be using this outside of a directive.**

Comment: Is it possible to compile an element already rendered on the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [THIS](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/) series of posts. It shows exactly what you are looking for.